# Funding for MathML rendering library

Tags: c++, svg, renderer, mathml

I have an unfinished MathML rendering library written in C++. I ceased development a few months ago due to lack of time. The library [still] uses the TrueType version (unsupported) of the STIX fonts beta [version 1.0 of the STIX fonts (OpenType Postscript format) has since been released].

Development of this kind of library is a HUGE undertaking and, in fact, requires a number of programmers/developers. In my case, I am doing it alone, and here's my question:

Does anyone of you know of any foundations/philanthropists who may be interested to fund my project in return for open sourcing the code?

The funding will serve as an incentive for me to finish the library - perhaps by taking a sabbatical :p - and, of course, as 'payment' for the intellectual property involved.

I've searched the web, contacted some [e.g., foundations, VCs, angels, etc.], but I either did not get a response (from VCs and angels) or was rejected (one reason is geography since these foundations support only US-based projects).

As an aside, when I search the web for MathML, the results are often outdated. I guess there's not much activity concerning MathML. Yet, I believe this library will be very useful not only to developers but also to anyone who uses math, especially students and teachers. It is useful for e-learning, can be used with desktop apps and web servers (Windows), makes it easy to insert images of formulas in PowerPoint documents, etc.

Any suggestions are most welcome. Thank you.

---

**EDITS:** I have finished this library finally without funding, although I don't rule out seeking one.

You can find my new site below with lots of sample formulas; click on the download link to download the SDK.

http://reformath.webnode.com/ (preferred for statistical reason)

http://reformath.weebly.com/ (please use the above link instead)

DON'T forget to provide some feedback - or donations. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Have you tried contacting the shuttleworth foundation? They are the ones behind quite a few open source freeware things like ubuntu

Comment: Generally it's hard to get funding for anything without already having an established backing of investors or revenue stream. You will need a prototype that can demonstrate the usefulness and possibilities to interest such people. Even then it can waste more time trying to get support than just finishing it. "I have this really cool idea that's partially started and has great potential when it's working" will interest geeks but not suits.

Answer (score 1):

Since we've already got open source MathML (Firefox has had it for years) that mean you'd have to do something better than the existing OSS solutions. And at that point, why not work on an existing open source project?

So that leaves commercial apps that may want a closed library for MathML rendering. I would go after companies like the makers of MathCad, Matlab, or any other engineering software that may want to display equations neatly. You should have something that already works for some subset of the things you/they will want it to do. You should also turn yourself into a company before going to those places so they take you seriously and you can license it to multiple customers. Otherwise the most you're likely to get is a job offer where they'd like you to hand over what you've got (for free if they can get you to) and then work on it as an employee - which may be all you want if you love it and hate your day job ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably ask on www-math list, also if you ask there, we can list your application in the software implementations page

http://www.w3.org/Math/Software/